# Jquery 2 random lists displaying side by side

Tags: jquery, math, random

I'm building a simple random div displayer.

I want to display one random li from the "featured" ul and two from the "others" ul. see below -

```
<ul id="featured">
I want to display one from this list
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Dog</li>
</ul>

<p>

<p>
<ul id ="others">
I want to display two from this list
<li>bird</li>
<li>monkey</li>
<li>Otter</li>
<li>Honey badger ( most awesome animal )</li>
</ul>
</p>
```

I'm using this code for the first ul -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

this.randomtip = function(){
    var length = $("#featured li").length; // this is where we put the id of the list
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $("#featured li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
};

$(document).ready(function(){   
    randomtip();
});

</script>
```

and this CSS

```
#featured, #featured li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    }
#featured{
    width:250px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:120%;
    float:left;
    }
#featured li{
    padding:20px;
    width: 500px;
    display:none; /* hide the items at first only to display one with javascript */
    }
```

But I can't get it to work with the second option. any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So what does not work? does your ported code work for the first UL? Do you have a second function that does not work for the second UL? or are you trying to reuse the first function for the section div?

Comment: So I've tried to use - 




<script type="text/javascript">

this.randomtip = function(){
    var length = $("#featured li").length; // this is where we put the id of the list
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $("#featured li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    $("#others li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
};

$(document).ready(function(){   
    randomtip();
});

</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [**jQuery :random filter**](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/) you can do the following very easily:

#### jQuery

```
$('#featured > li, #others > li').hide();
$('#featured > li:random').show();

var i = 2;
while (i--) $('#others > li:hidden:random').show();
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y7cLr/2

Comment: Thanks Gary! Looks to be working a treat on Fiddle but when I try to copy it over to my local html file it won't work. I've added jquery using the google api and put in the correct script type for the javascript and css.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure your putting your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* [....] your code here [....] */ });` so it only acts on the DOM elements when they are ready. Also make sure you got that jQuery random filter plugin. Do `alert(jQuery);` to see if jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Missing the ready function :-/ . Again thanks for the response!